# Second argument (controller) to handlebars each helper. What does it mean?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to analyse TodoMVC's Ember example. What does the second argument to the #each helper mean?

```
<ul id="todo-list">
    {{#each filteredTodos itemController="todo"}}
        <li {{bindAttr class="isCompleted:completed isEditing:editing"}}>
            {{#if isEditing}}
                {{view Todos.EditTodoView todoBinding="this"}}
            {{else}}
                {{view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding="isCompleted" class="toggle"}}
                <label {{action "editTodo" on="doubleClick"}}>{{title}}</label>
                <button {{action "removeTodo"}} class="destroy"></button>
            {{/if}}
            </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

It's supposed to be an option hash but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sets the `itemController` property of the current controller (`TodosController` I presume) to `todo` i.e the instance of the `TodoController`.

That means that every item (`<li>` element) will be binded not to the `TodosController` but to a `TodoController` instance.

`isEditing` looks for the property on the instance of `TodoController` and `{{ action "removeTodo" }}` will call `removeTodo` function on `TodoController`.

Comment: OK, but could I declare it in the TodosController like here: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html?

So every ArrayController has the itemController property which relates to a single model item?

Comment: Yes, it should work if you declare it in the `TodosController` class. And yes, `itemController` is a property of any `Ember.ArrayController`